# How to Hide a Textbox with only CSS

Tags: css, textbox

Can I hide the following textbox using only CSS without using javascript?

```
<input id="customer_custom1" name="customer[custom1]" type="text" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**css:**

```
#customer_custom1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I swear I tried that before I posted this question. It's late and I must have missed a typo... thanks!!!